# How to order array of objects in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have a live API which has data in JSON format and I trying to display it on my website (for web development learning). I did request the data have a the data displayed on my website but the problem is how do I order my data by 'Country"? Any help please

```
"countries": [
{
  "country": "United States",
  "countryCode": "US",
},
{
  "country": "Spain",
  "countryCode": "ES",
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: @Igor Beat me to it.

Comment: And first just use `JSON.parse()` to deserialize your JSON string, unless you already have an object.

Comment: Thanks @Igor . It works.

Answer (score 1):

U can try

```
sortbyKey(obj,key){
  return obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = a[key],
      keyB = b[key];
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

}
```

example is below

```js
var list={"countries": [
{
  "country": "United States",
  "countryCode": "US",
},
{
  "country": "Spain",
  "countryCode": "ES",
}
]
}

function sortbyKey(obj,key){
  return obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = a[key],
      keyB = b[key];
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  
}
list.countries=sortbyKey(list.countries,"country")

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a model class that represents your incoming object as shown below -

```
export class Countries {
    country: string;
    countryCode: string;
}
```

Then initialize it as an array of objects -

```
countriesModel : Countries [] = [];
```

Convert your JSON to a model by parsing it -

```
this.countryModel = JSON.parse(your_country-object);
```

After that call the sortCountries function and pass the property in the object on which you want to sort -

```
this.sortCountries(p => p.country, 'ASC');
```

Finally, your sort functions body should look something like this -

```
sortCountries<T>(countryName: (c: countriesModel) => T, order: 'ASC' | 'DESC'): void {
this.countriesModel.sort((a, b) => {
  if (countryName(a) < countryName(b)) {
    return -1;`enter code here`
  } else if (countryName(a) > countryName(b)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

if (order === 'DESC') {
  this.countriesModel.reverse();
}
```

}